# Mock private, class-level instance property using Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to mock a private, class-level instance property so that I can assert on it to see if it is being called. In this particular case it is a NestJs Logger instance, but I believe the question is a broader one.

Here is the class under test:

```js
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

export class SomeService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(SomeService.name);

  methodUnderTest(someNumber: number): string {
 
    if (someNumber === 5) {
      return 'Greater';
    else {
      this.logger.error('It is definitely not 5.');
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my (attempt at a) test class:

```js
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

jest.mock('@nestjs/common');  // This is causing the error below.

const someService = new SomeService();

describe('SomeService - methodUnderTest', () => {

  it('should call logger.error when someNumber is not 5', () => {

     someService.methodUnderTest(2);

     expect(Logger.error).toHaveBeenCalled();  // This is incorrect.
  }

}
```

I know this isn't correct.  I was wondering if I had to use a spy, but wasn't sure how to make that work.  Currently I'm receiving this error upon execution of the test:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: index_1.Injectable is not a function

  at Object.<anonymous> (../.yarn/__virtual__/@nestjs-common-virtual-992fab1572/0/cache/@nestjs-common-npm-8.2.4-cc0ecb2b32-a2945b7fb7.zip/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/parse-float.pipe.js:40:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (../.yarn/__virtual__/@nestjs-common-virtual-992fab1572/0/cache/@nestjs-common-npm-8.2.4-cc0ecb2b32-a2945b7fb7.zip/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/index.js:8:22)
```

Comment: Mocking private implementation details is a canonical thing to not do. Invert the dependency, or at least give yourself the option to - if `new Logger(SomeService.name)` was the default value of a parameter property, you could easily pass in a test double and assert on interactions with it (especially if the requirement was for the _interface_, something with an error method, not the concrete _class_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was indeed to use a spy.  The error was being thrown by this line, which is not needed at all actually:

```
jest.mock('@nestjs/common');
```

Here's the working solution; quite simple in the end:

```
import {describe, expect, it, jest } from '@jest/globals';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

const loggerSpy = jest.spyOn(Logger.prototype, 'error');
const someService = new SomeService();

describe('SomeService - methodUnderTest', () => {

  it('should call logger.error when someNumber is not 5', () => {
    someService.methodUnderTest(2);

    expect(loggerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }
}
```